# terminal emulators like Cathode?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line

This is cool: http://osxdaily.com/2011/01/27/the-ultimate-retro-terminal-cathode/

Are there any similar applications for Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you looking for the grainy, discolored look? Or do you just want to change the colors? You can change the colors to black and green in Terminal preferences.

Comment: the grainy discolored look...

Comment: @root45 Cathode is much more than just a color scheme. Look at the [animated effects in this screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CP_4ZJEIH3U&t=1m28s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just stumbled upon `terminology`, which is the terminal shipping with the enlightenment window manager. It's defaults already have a quite nice retro feel and it is available in the ubuntu main repo.

```
apt install terminology
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a new (actually one year old) terminal emulator project that does exactly what you want: [cool-retro-term](https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term) (and I agree, it's really cool!).

Ubuntu users can install it from this ppa: `ppa:bugs-launchpad-net-falkensweb/cool-retro-term` or compile it from source:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential qmlscene qt5-qmake qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev qtdeclarative5-controls-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin libqt5qml-graphicaleffects qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin qtdeclarative5-window-plugin
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term.git
cd cool-retro-term
qmake && make
./cool-retro-term
```

Comment: Yes it is! But probably not for every day use :D

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: Ok, maybe it is for everyday use, it's badass!

Comment: @Fabby you're right, i just provided some installation details!

Comment: Much better!  Upvoted!  **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

There are none like Cathode for Ubuntu. It's an OSX thing.

Comment: Their [FAQ](http://www.secretgeometry.com/apps/cathode/faq/#linux) says "**Any plans for a Linux port?** One day, but not yet." Also, the `apple2` module of the `xscreensaver` package [can be used as a terminal emulator](http://www.jwz.org/blog/2011/01/cathode-vintage-terminal-emulator/) (most likely you'll need the real package and not the stripped one that Ubuntu distributes).

Comment: Actually when I said "Ubuntu" I meant "Gnome".

Comment: Happily, the apple2 screensaver works fine: install the xscreensaver-data-extra package and then run as: /usr/lib/xscreensaver/apple2 -text -fast -program bash

Answer (score 0):

From sil's comment:

**Happily, the apple2 screensaver works fine: install the xscreensaver-data-extra package and then run as: /usr/lib/xscreensaver/apple2 -text -fast -program bash**

(I copied this into a separate answer because being just a comment I almost miss it.  It's just too amazing that this existed for such a long time and very little people knew about it.)

Answer (score 0):

I am big fan of  cathode look. But there is no terminal out their made specifically keeping cathode/vintage terminal in mind.

I installed [Yakuake](https://github.com/KDE/yakuake) (terminal dropdown emulator) and it had the option of customizing its appearance. Select the Green on Black option. This is not so bad.

[image]

I guess every terminal, even the one that comes default with Ubuntu have customizing properties. You can always choose a green font,a black backgroud and voilaa!!